# $C([a,b]), \| \cdot \|_\infty$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification

I have to prove that $(C([a,b]), \| \cdot \|_\infty )$ is complete. I proved that a Cauchy sequence converges pointwise. Now, let's call $f$ the pointwise limit. I have: \begin{align}
| f_n(x)-f_m(x) | \le \epsilon \ \ \forall n,m > n_0, \forall x
\end{align}
So by the continuity of $| \cdot|$, I can let $n\to\infty$, so I obtain $ f_n\to f $ in $ \|\cdot\|_\infty$. Now I have to prove that $f$ is continuous. Here I'm not completely sure. Let $x_n \to x$ and fix $\epsilon$, I have:
\begin{align}
 |f(x_n)-f(x)| \le |f(x_n)-f_m(x_n)|+|f_m(x_n)-f_m(x)|+|f_m(x)-f(x)|
\end{align}
By the pointwise convergence, I can select $f_m$ s.t.
\begin{align}
& |f(x_n)-f_m(x_n)|\le \epsilon/3, |f_m(x)-f(x)|\le \epsilon/3 \  \ \text{so,} \\&|f(x_n)-f(x)| \le |f_m(x_n)-f_m(x)|+2\epsilon/3
\end{align}
So, by the continuity of $f_m$, $ \exists n_0 \  s.t. \ \  |f_m(x_n)-f_m(x)| \le \epsilon/3$.

Is this proof okay? Is there some other way to prove the continuity of $f$?

Comment: What is $n_0$ doing (it doesn't appear to be used)?  Also $n_0$ might depend on $m$.  Hint: this space is not complete.  Try to find a sequence of functions which approach a jump discontinuity.

Comment: The "$\epsilon/3$" argument is the classic way of proving that a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Since $f_n $ is Cauchy, then $\forall \epsilon \exists n_0$ s.t. $| f_n(x)-f_m(x) | \le \epsilon \ \ \forall n,m > n_0, \forall x$. So letting $n\to \infty$, $| f(x)-f_m(x) | \le \epsilon \ \ \forall m > n_0, \forall x$, and taking the $\sup$ over $x$ I get the uniform convergence. I know this space to be complete, it can't be. Can you provide a counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not valid because $m$ depends 0n $n$.

Choose $n_0$ such that $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$ for al $x$ for all $n,m \geq n_0$. You have  already noticed that $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists. Letting $n \to \infty$ we get $|f_m(x)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon$ for al $x$ for all $m \geq n_0$. In particular $$|f_{n_0}(x)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon$$ for all $x$. Now use the inequality

$|f(x)-f(y)|$$ $$ \leq |f(x)-f_{n_0}(x)|+|f_{n_0}(x)-f_{n_0}(y)|+|f_{n_0}(y)-f(y)|\leq 2\epsilon + |f_{n_0}(x)-f_{n_0}(y)|$.

Now complete the proof using the fact that $f_{n_0}$ is continuous.

(We have already proved that $f_m \to f$ uniformly).

Comment: Oh, okay. So, if I want to make my proof correct, I have to use the fact that $f_m \to f$,and select an m big enough, so that those equalities hold for all $x_n$?

Comment: Right. Note that sequential form of continuity makes things messy and that is where your proof gets into trouble.

Comment: Yes it's true, the topological definition is better in this case, I wanted to be sure I understood the mistake. Thanks for your time.